# jQuery при клике изменяется ширина страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку изменялась ширина страницы (или блока внутри страницы)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью стилей:

```js
function setBoxWidth() {
  $(".box").css("width", "400px");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">test</div> <br />

<button onclick="setBoxWidth()">Изменить ширину</button>
```

Comment: `<br>` является пустым элементом, это означает, что он не имеет содержимого и закрывающего тега

Comment: Все верно написано, лучше почитайте о html разметке :)

Comment: почему <br /> неверная запись? это XHTML

Comment: @soledar10, в XHTML да, только `<br />`, потому что в XML все теги должны быть закрыты. А тут HTML, не нужен слеш лишний и уже написал первым комментом почему

Comment: @soledar10, допустим `<br></br>` = `<br />`. При `<br></br>` браузер преобразует уже два отсупа `<br><br>`. Чем не пруф?

Comment: HTML5 допускает использование слеша, это не будет ошибкой, можете проверить валидатором

Comment: @soledar10, ну погнали тогда и `input` с `img` закрывать

Comment: @Doofy а почему нет? это уже дело каждого

Comment: @soledar10, никто и не говорил что это ошибка, это небрежный код. Если так нравится пихать в код, чего не нужно, пишите

Comment: Благодарю! Мне это и требовалось.